# traverse 2 million records

Tags: apex

I have 2 million records stored in account and I have two fields shippedzipcode and billingzipcode in account object. I want to compare values in these two fields and store the result in an list variable. I do not need entire code but I want to understand how I can handle 2 millions records for comparison. A small code snippet would be of great help.

Comment: Personally, I'd look at Batch classes for a job of this size if you haven't already.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to store all of this information in a list? Why do you need to process all of this information at once? What are you trying to accomplish by comparing the billing and shipping zip/postal codes? Without additional information (and likely even with additional information), it doesn't make much sense to compute this information more than once (based on both the volume of records, and the fact that billing and shipping zip/postal codes aren't likely to change frequently). Depending on the comparison you're making, this could be accomplished with a formula field.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you I'd look at a [Batch class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm) if you're going to be iterating over that volume of records. A batch class typically had 3 parts to it: `start()`, `execute()` and `finish()`. Here's a skeleton below:

```
global class MyCoolBatchClass implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

    String query;

    global MyCoolBatchClass() {

    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope) {

    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

    }

}
```

In this instance, you're just going to query something like:

```
String query = 'SELECT Id FROM Account';
```

Then in the `execute()` method which expects and returns a `List<sObject>` (which will just be your Ids), do you query and comparison in there.

For instance:

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope) {
    List<Account> accList = [SELECT Name, BillingZipCode, ShippingZipCode FROM Account WHERE Id IN :scope];

    // Do more stuff...
}
```

A batch class typically iterates over 200 records at a time and can be used to iterate over 50 million records, at 200 a time. Although you can change the batch number.

There's a few ways to execute batch classes, you can schedule them although you'd need a class for that or you can simply execute it anonymously:

```
Id myBatchClassUniqueIdThingy = Database.executeBatch(new MyCoolBatchClass, 200);
```

The first parameter in `Database.executeBatch` is the name you gave your Batch class and the second is how many records to iterate over at a time.

Comment: Wish the use of dynamic (string based) SOQL would be removed from the documentation example. The choice of static or dynamic SOQL is unrelated to this being a batchable and generally static makes more sense. Also no need for the class to be global anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You need to try this using Apex Batch Class

```
public class BatchClass implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
          return Database.getQueryLocator([Select Id,shippedzipcode,billingzipcode from Account]); 
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){
        //Logic that you need to work on If you want to store a List add database.stateful which will hold the state between transaction
    }        
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){       
       //doSomething once all the batch execution is finished e.g. send an email out
    }      
}
```

Comment: @Derek, OK I use a batch apex, but assume there are 1 Lakh resulting matching records. Now what to do with these 1 lakh records is not what I am looking at for the time being. I just want to know is is there a way we can capture the 1lakh records in to some variable or is it impossible?

Comment: @Derek and also how to use a formula field??